# How to update custom price in Total after select shipping method in Magento 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, shipping

I have a dropdown on shipping method step and I want to update price as shipping price if someone select an option from dropdown. It should updated Shipping price and Grand total.

Can anyone help me in this?

[image: Checkout Image]